# How do I get out of the void?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am stuck in the void after respawning in creative mode pe. I am unable to tap the pause button or place blocks because I am in the void. I also cannot fly or break blocks. I can see what is on the surface of the world, but I cannot tap the options button!

This was easier to fix on my Kindle, but now I have an iPad.

Comment: What did you do in order to fix the issue on your Kindle?

Comment: You should be able to fly... How did you get there in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Simply double click the home button and  close the app completely. Go back into the app and try to get into the world again. If you are stil stuck in this void, double click again and slide it out of your app history, then reopen the app and delete the world.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, in PE all you have to do is quit the game then go back in,  but before going in switch to survival mode by clicking the options button next to your world and choose survival mode. Then click back and click your world. Once you get back in you will start to die as you're in the void! Once you die choose to respawn and bam, you're back at the last place you slept.

If you want to go back to creative again just quit and repeat the steps and switch to creative before going back in to your world.

Answer (score -1):

Turn off your device. (Shutdown all the way)
Turn it back on.
Open minecraft and Delete the world.

Answer (score -1):

Go off the app and double click the home button twice to close the app completely. Now go back on minecraft PE and tap on the world. While waiting for the world to load, get ready to double tap the jump/flying button. Once the world has loaded quickly double tap and fly up to the bedrock and fly around looking for the light, which will be a hole to get back in to the overland. Make sure that the light you are following isn't the moon/sun/a star because you can get lost really quickly in the void. This way you won't have to delete the world unless you get lost. Keep trying till you get it, GOOD LUCK!!!